# How to fully migrate data from dynamodb to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, migration, dynamodb

I have large data set inside dynamodb and want to move them all to postgresql and only can have 1 hour downtime. Whats the best tool or option to migrate and map all of my data from dynamo to postgres without losing any?

I tried handeling manually in javascript but lost so many data.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! How much data do you have? Be aware that even with SSDs, it'll take a while to transfer data. And indexes - they'll take a while to write also! You're going to have to provide much more information. What are your tables' structures with DynamoDB? What is your proposed new schema? How much I/O have you provisioned on Amazon for DynamoDB? Are you using PostgreSQL on-prem or also hosted? If so, with whom?

Comment: Oh, didn't except someone answer. Thank you. I use dynamodb to collect sales data from aamzon and right now I have problem with doing fast search on multiple tables. I don't mind if it gets 10 hours even. my largest table is about 3 gigabytes. Btw I want to buy postgres on aws but don't know which plan should I buy or even is it fasater than dynamodb or am I making a mistake to change to postgres. I hope you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: I can't recommend a specific Amazon PostgreSQL plan - but what I **can** suggest that you do is to set up a PostgreSQL instance on your home machine - download all of your AmazonDB data and the put it into a PG schema locally - you **will** make mistakes - then when your PG schema is ready and you are happy with its characteristics, you can set up a PG instance on the cloud - pay close attention to I/O charges (and all of the other ones!). Since this is a one-off process, you will have to have down-time - just grin and bear it, you may want to pay for DynamoDB for faster I/O during the process

Comment: Thank you again. Is there any better hosting than aws for postgres?

Comment: As I said, I can't recommend a specific PG cloud provider - it's been a while since I've used any of them! Be careful about versions and what extensions they will or will not allow - if you have any, check that they'll work. Of course, you could set up your own instance either from source or using a .rpm/.deb on a cloud VM? I'll leave it to you to check out what the various vendors offer! HDD/SSD? I/O? You'll have to have an idea of your application's profile in order to pick the plan/vendor that corresponds to your needs!